# The shapes of image read from CV2 and Pillow are different

Tags: python, opencv, python-imaging-library

I have an image read from cv2.imread, the shape is (2320, 1744, 3). However, when I use Pillow, the results are very different:

```
a = PIL.Image.open('mypic')
a.size # => (2320, 1744)
b = np.asarray(a)
b.shape # => (1744, 2320, 3)
```

Why is it automatically transposed?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Different pixel information in PIL and cv2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50912978/different-pixel-information-in-pil-and-cv2) Also, I doubt, that the shape is `(2320, 1744, 3)`, when opened with OpenCV, and the actual width is 2320. It most likely will be `(1744, 2320, 3)`, too.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to HansHirse, the post helps me a lot. But Pillow still works strangely.

The shapes of  two different images read from cv2 are the same while are different read from Pillow, as seen bellow.

```
import cv2
a = cv2.imread("0.jpg")
a.shape # (2320, 1744, 3)
b = cv2.imread("1.jpg")
b.shape # (2320, 1744, 3)
c = Image.open("0.jpg")
print(c.mode, c.size, c.format)
# RGB (2320, 1744) JPEG

d = Image.open("1.jpg")
print(d.mode, d.size, d.format)
# RGB (1744, 2320) JPEG
```

Comment: Are those probably images taken with a mobile phone camera or similar? Sometimes, the orientation is taken into account, and images get rotated automatically. Maybe, just provide the images in question in your actual question.

Comment: Yes, the two images are taken with a mobile phone. I made some bugs since I can't find any documents about how PIL reads an image.

Answer (score 0):

CV2 (in some versions) take orientation into account, see this for details: [Image Orientation (python+openCV)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44537075/image-orientation-pythonopencv)

I found this, um, interesting feature when trying to read some images with identical properties:

```
% identify images/*
images/425464_1_1340_111_2.jpg JPEG 4000x3000 4000x3000+0+0 8-bit sRGB 2.70603MiB 0.000u 0:00.006
images/440143_2_2376_142_2.jpg JPEG 4000x3000 4000x3000+0+0 8-bit sRGB 5332750B 0.010u 0:00.005
```

Loading them with CV2 to read their size, I find:

```
>>> x = cv2.imread('images/425464_1_1340_111_2.jpg')
>>> x.shape (3000, 4000, 3)
>>> x = cv2.imread('images/440143_2_2376_142_2.jpg')
>>> x.shape (4000, 3000, 3)
```

I needed the behavior from `identify`, but using `PIL.Image.open()` and `size` seemed to work.

Answer (score -1):

PIL reads the images with axis in the order of cols, row, channel, or more easily said as x,y,channel.
Other image reading packages (i.e. cv2) get the axis in order of row, col, channel (or y,x,channel). This approach is more familiar for people, especially when working with satellite or aerial imagery.
You could read with either PIL or cv2 just be aware for the axis locations.